# Script to send email to multiple addresses

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, automation, google-sheets

I am using a Google Sheet to send an automated pre-filled email whenever someone fills out the required fields in the Google Sheet. How can I make the following script send to different emails based on the location the user enters?  For example if user enters London send email to email1@email.com or if user enters Paris send email to email2@email.com.  Also, do I need to add a trigger for Google Sheets to know when to initiate this script?

```js
function fireEmail(e){
  var userName = e.values[1];
  var timeStamp = e.values[0];
  var medalType1 = e.values[2];
  var medalType2 = e.values[3];
  var medalColor = e.values[4];
  var medalRecipient = e.values[5];
  var dateNeeded = e.values[6];
  var medalLocation = e.values[7];


  var emailBodyHTML = [];
  emailBodyHTML += '<b>You have received a medal request from ' + userName + '.</b>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Onboarding Ops Medal Type, If Applicable: ' + medalType1 + '</p>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Service Ops Medal Type, If Applicable: ' + medalType2 + '</p>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Medal Color: ' + medalColor + '</p>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Medal Recipient: ' + medalRecipient + '</p>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Medal Needed by: ' + dateNeeded + '</p>';
  emailBodyHTML += '<p>Please visit <a href="place.com">the medaling document</a> to manage this request.</p>';

  var emailSubject = 'New Medal Request for ' + medalLocation + '!';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email1@email.com",
    name: "Medaling Request",
    subject: emailSubject,


    htmlBody: emailBodyHTML    
  });

}
```

Comment: To add a button, insert an image, then attach the script to the image. Try hacking the spreadsheet in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926001/templated-email-using-apps-script-based-on-data-in-google-sheets/34929081#34929081

Answer (score 1):

To check the location you can use an [if-statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) (after your htlm body)

```
var mailTo;
if (medalLocation == 'London') {
mailTo = 'abc@gmail.com';
} else if (medalLocation == 'Paris' { 
mailTo = 'def@gmail.com';
}
```

If you only have two locations, you can also use a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(VS.94).aspx):

```
var mailTo = (medalLocation == 'London') ? 'abc@gmail.com' : 'def@gmail.com'
```

If, on the other hand you have more locations to check, I would advice the use of a [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

```
var mailTo;
switch(medalLocation) {
case 'London':
    mailTo = 'abc@gmail.com';
    break;
case 'Paris':
    mailTo = 'def@gmail.com';
    break;
case 'Brussels':
    mailTo = 'ghi@gmail.com';
    break; 
default:
    mailTo = 'jkl@gmail.com';
}
```

Then, after your 'mailTo' is determined, change the mail part to

```
 MailApp.sendEmail({
to: mailTo,
name: "Medaling Request",
subject: emailSubject
htmlBody: emailBodyHTML
```

});

The script should have a on Form submit trigger.
Hope this helps ?